# C , Why does this code work with array notation , but not with pointer notation?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement my own strcpy function , here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void Strcat(char *p1,char*p2)
{
    while(*p1!='\0'){p1++;}; //this increments the pointer till the end of the array (it then points to the last element which is '\0')

    while(*p2!='\0'){*p1++=*p2++;};
}
int main()
{
    char txt1[]="hell";
    char txt2[]="o!";

    printf("before :%s\n",txt1);
    Strcat(txt1,txt2);
    printf("after :%s\n",txt1);

}
```

Everything works fine .

However , when I change

```
char txt1[]="hell";
char txt2[]="o!";
```

to

```
char *txt1="hell";
char *txt2="o!";
```

I face a Segmentation fault ,

Why is that ?

Aren't they ( both initialization methods) equivalent ?
Aren't "txt1" and "txt2" both act like a pointer to the first element of the char array ?

Comment: Note: `while(*p2!='\0'){*p1++=*p2++;};` fails to add a NUL to the destination. `while(*p1++ = *p2++) {;}` could fix this.

Comment: There is not "pointer notation" or "array notation", but completely different types. A pointer is not an array is not a pointer!

Answer (score 0):

String literals are not modifiable and trying to modify them invokes *undefined behavior*.

`char txt1[]="hell";` is a character array, so modyfying its contents is allowed.

`char *txt1="hell";` is a pointer to a string literal, so you must not modify what is pointed.